# How to call dispatch action from child component in react?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have an `App` component, a `Login` component. 
In my login page when user successfully gives his credential, the API returns the user data as response. I want to store that user data as a global state. That's why I used `redux`.

My **index.js** file content:

```
const saveUserData = (state = {
  user: {}
}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "UPDATE_USER":
      state = {
          ...state,
          user: action.payload
      };
      break;
  }
  return state;
};

const store = createStore(saveUserData);

store.subscribe( () => {
  console.log(state.getState());
});

render(
    <Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>
    , window.document.getElementById('app'));
```

In my **App.js** file:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Root>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}/>
            <Route exact path="/register" component={Register}/>
            <Route exact path='/books' component={Books}/>
            <Route path='/books/:id' component={BookDetail}/>
          </Root>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
  };
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    userData: state.saveUserData
  }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    updateUser: (user) => {
      dispatch({
        type: "UPDATE_USER",
        payload: user
      })
    }
  }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

In my **Login.js** file:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!event.target.checkValidity()) {
      return;
    }

    const {email, password, remember_me} = this.state.formData;
    const url = api.api_url + "auth/login";

    fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: new Headers({
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }),
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: email,
        password: password,
        remember_me: remember_me
      }),
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
    .then(response => {
      if (typeof response.access_token == "undefined")
        this.setState({display_errors: true, errors: response.error.user_authentication});
      else{
        localStorage.setItem('jwtToken', response.access_token);
        this.props.updateUser(response.user); // Here I want to call the dispatcher to save the response user data in global store
        this.props.history.push({
          pathname: '/',
          state: {message: response.message}
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

In login component i want to call the `App` component's dispatcher method `updateUser` with `this.props.updateUser(response.user);`. But it's not working.

Does anyone have any idea how can I achieve that? You can see full code in [github](https://github.com/imtiaz-emu/reactjs-template/tree/p_fe)

Comment: you should connect your `Login` with the `mapDispacth` to get the right prop, there is no need to connect `App`

Comment: @h1b9b, could you please elaborate your thoughts? I didn't quite understand your comment :(

Comment: `connect` the components that dispatch actions/need data from the store and only those components. If a component isn't dispatching or using data from the store (typically) don't `connect` it.

Comment: App.js: use return dispatch. like `....(user) => {
     return dispatch({`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things first.

`saveUserData` is your reducer as it seems, why it should be exposed in `props`? Only the data from state that is relevant to your component should be made available to props by using `mapStateToProps`. So, for example, if you had a user data like `currentUser` in your state that actually is used in your component, then you should do-

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    currentUser: state.currentUser
  };
};
```

Now, inside the component, you could do- `this.props.currentUser` to get the data.

The next important bit is, you need to use `bindActionCreators` from `redux`. Define the action in `actions.js` and then in your component file-

```
import {updateUser} from 'path/to/actions.js'
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
...

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return bindActionCreators({updateUser}, dispatch);
};
```

And finally-

`export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);`

**EDIT:**

Checked your github repo. I think the first problem is importing `Login` component as `{Login}` in `App.js`, which should be `import Login` instead as it's exported as default from `Login.js`

The second thing is using the component in render attribute of `Route`, like below-

`<Route exact path="/login" render={() => (<Login/>)}/>`

This solved the issue for me, so should do the same for you.

Comment: I've done this. But when I call `this.props.updateUser()` then in console: this.props.updateUser is not a function.

Answer (score 1):

this is How I would do it. First of all, you don't need to connect your app.js to store as it is not using any state or dispatching action. Make it a functional component.

```
const App = () => {
  render() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Root>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}/>
            <Route exact path="/register" component={Register}/>
            <Route exact path='/books' component={Books}/>
            <Route path='/books/:id' component={BookDetail}/>
          </Root>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
  };
}

export default App;
```

It is the best practice to add a default case to your switch statement.

```
const saveUserData = (state = {
  user: {},
  display_errors: false,
  errors: {}
}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "UPDATE_USER":
      state = {
          ...state,
          user: action.payload
      };
     case "DISPLAY_ERRORS":
      state = {
          ...state,
          errors: action.payload,
          display_errors: true
      };
     default: 
     return state;
  } 
};
```

Create a separate action file and move your fetch request inside the actions.js

```
export default updateUser = (email, password, remember_me) => dispatch => {
fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: new Headers({
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }),
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: email,
        password: password,
        remember_me: remember_me
      }),
    })
    .then(res => res.json()).
    .then(response => {
  if (typeof response.access_token == "undefined")
    dispatch({type: DISPLAY_ERRORS, payload: response.error.user_authentication });
  else{
    localStorage.setItem('jwtToken', response.access_token);

  }
});
    .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))

}
```

Then you can import this action file and can access the updateUser where ever you want to use.

```
import { updateUser } from "action.js";

//now you have access to this function 
this.props.updateUser(email, password, remember_me);
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  //state.....
})
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { updateUser })(Login);
```

Comment: where should I put `mapStateToProps` const? Also, if I move my `fetch` code in an actions file, how can I update my `Login` component states (e.g. display_erros, errors)?

Comment: Updated the post with mapStateToProps and display errors. You don't need to use setState as that's why redux is for. Also dispatch action for errors.

Comment: I have made changes to show you an example. You can create a case in reducers for errors.

Comment: I did what you've posted. Thanks for your effort (+1). But the problem is in my **Login.js** file `this.props.updateUser(email, password, remember_me);` returns error updateUser is undefined.

Comment: can you make a code example codesandbox.io .Then I will look into it

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should store your `updateUser` method inside an actions file, and import that method where ever you need to use it.

**actions.js**

```
export const updateUser = (user) => {
  dispatch({
    type: "UPDATE_USER",
    payload: user
  })
}
```

Then, where ever you want to use it you can use:

```
import { updateUser } from 'path/to/actions.js'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'; 

...

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return bindActionCreators({
    updateUser
  }, dispatch);
};
```

When you find you have a whole bunch of actions, which you probably will when your app expands in size and complexity, this approach will help you to manage your actions properly.

Always consider **[Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)** - the purpose of your **actions.js** file is to contain all of your actions, nothing else, and it is much better placed here than in the **app.js** file. However, further still I would personally have an **actions** folder, and contain this method inside a **user.js** file in that directory.

I hope this helps.

### Edit

I have added use of `bindActionCreators` to `mapDispatchToProps`. Sorry its been a while since I did it this way - I personally export `store.dispatch` from my **app.js** and import and use that where I need to, rather than using `mapDispatchToProps`. I can explain further if you like, but really it is good practice to use the `mapDispatchToProps` method provided.

Comment: In this approach shouldn't I need to `connect` my component?

Comment: Yes, you would need to `connect` it. Otherwise, as I mentioned in my edit - you could use `export const dispatch = store.dispatch;` inside **app,js**, and import it to your component along with the action from the actions file. Then just simply use `dispatch(updateUser(user))`

Comment: I've added the `actions.js` file with the code you've given. I did also add `export const dispatch = store.dispatch;` inside app,js, and import it to **login.js** file with the action from actions file. But the problem is in app.js `store` is undefined.

Comment: Where are you running the `createStore()` method for for redux store? Where ever that is, have it as `const store = createStore()`. Sorry i assumed you had created it in app.js

Answer (score 0):

As the user above states, it is better to consider separation of concern. This is what I would do:

- create a complete set of redux lifecycle files for each scope e.g. `login`. That includes actions, sagas, and reducers.
- for each scope in your case `login`, I would route its link to a `container` which has access to `global state` with `connect()`. That component alone has access to dispatch and its children components should only refer to it for dispatches keeping them dumb and maintain source of truth.

NOTE: as long as you use the redux life cycle, **it doesn't matter where you are calling the action creator from** it will be available to your global state as long as it has `connect()`

Answer (score 0):

you can add and change the following in app.js

```
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import * as actionCreators from "../yourActionFile"

class App extends React.Component {

   handleSubmit(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       this.props.updateUser(("yourArgumentsHere"))
   }


          render() {
            return (
                <BrowserRouter>
                  <Root>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                    <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}/>
                    <Route exact path="/register" component={Register}/>
                    <Route exact path='/books' component={Books}/>
                    <Route path='/books/:id' component={BookDetail}/>
                  </Root>
                </BrowserRouter>
            );
          };
        }

        const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
          return {
            userData: state.saveUserData
          }
        };

        const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
        return {
          updateUser: bindAtionCreators(actionCreators.updateUser, dispatch)
          //the logic for updating your store or "global state" should be done in the reducer
          }
        }
      };


      export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

you can either pass the handleSubmit function down to the child as props or you can add the mapDispatchToProps and handleSubmit to the child component. Either way, if you are relying on the store for all dynamic data in your app the changes will trickle down once the the store has been updated by the reducer.

Answer (score 0):

```
interface YourComponentProps {
    dispatch: Dispatch<any>

}

class YourComponentPanel extends Component< YourComponentProps, YourComponentProps > {

     constructor(props: YourComponentProps) {
          super(props);
          this.state = { ...props };

     }

     componentDidMount(): void {
         this.state.dispatch( someAction( "someday" ) );
     }

     render(): React.ReactNode { 
         return (<Text>Im a Component</Text>);
     }

}

function YourComponentPanelDispatchWrapper(props) {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    return (<YourComponentPanel dispatch={dispatch}/>);
}
```

Typescript.  React-native but this will work in react.  Maybe it's naive.  but it for sure works.